# JComponent repaint() fails when window background has non-zero Opacity

Tags: java, swing, transparent, repaint, jcomponent

I've been stuck on this for a day. I'm trying to dynamically update a `BufferedImage` that I've painted on top of a transparent border-less window. But repaint() stops working as soon as the window background alpha value is set to anything other than full (`1.0f`);

I've tried `image_canvas.setOpaque(false)`, this did not resolve the issue.

Please let me know if anyone can find a workaround that would allow component `repaint()` to work on top of a transparent background.

Code below to reproduce the issue:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class Dynamic_Buffered_Image2 {

    static Window win;
    static JComponent image_canvas;
    static BufferedImage my_image;

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    // Create a test BufferedImage:
    my_image = new BufferedImage(100, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        my_image.setRGB(i, i, Color.BLUE.getRGB());

    // Create display window:
    create_win();

    // Modify the BufferedImage dynamically:
    for (int i = 0; i < my_image.getWidth(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < my_image.getHeight(); j++) {
            my_image.setRGB(i, j, Color.red.getRGB());
            Thread.sleep(10);
            win.repaint();
        }
    }
}

private static void create_win() {
    win = new Window(null);
    win.setSize(150, 150);
    image_canvas = new JComponent() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            g.drawImage(my_image, 0, 0, null);
        }
    };
    win.add(image_canvas);
    win.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 1.0f)); // Any opacity other than 1.0f breaks repaint()??? (no red lines)
    win.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made two changes:

```
//win.repaint();
image_canvas.repaint();
```

and:

```
image_canvas.setOpaque(true); // added
win.add(image_canvas);
```

Comment: You must be a magician, I could have sworn I tried every possible combination. Thank you, this solved my issue perfectly.